# RecyclerView set views to be recycled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

in my app, I'm implementing a recyclerview. My dataset for this recyclerview will have varying sizes according to the options that I set for the data to be displayed on the recyclerview.

One of the actions that I take with my recyclerview is to "expand" an item when a click is done on it, displaying further options in it. When pressing on this "expanded" item, I perform the action of "closing" it. Also, there can only be on "expanded" item at maximum at any moment.

The thing is that I understand that recyclerview recycles its row-views when they get out of sight for improved performance. However, because I am trying to have only one "expanded" item at a time, this recycling messes it up quite a lot.

What happens right now is that when I "expand", say the item related to position 1 of my dataset, as shown in the image below.

[image: item for position 1 "expanded"]

When I scroll down, I will see that the rowview for this item being recycled at a random chance since I will see this "expanded" view on items that I have not set to be "expanded", as shown in the image below.

[image: this happened for me only scrolling down through my recyclerview]

And of course, when this happens, then when I scroll back to the item that I have selected to "expand", it will be "closed" as you would have expected.

So I have been thinking that I could resolve this problem by setting the possible number of views to be something like 80% of my dataset size will decrease the possibility of this problem occurring while still reduced, but enjoy some improved performance.

Another solution I thought about was disabling this "expanded" view from being recycled for other views and when this "expanded" item's position comes into screen, it gets bounded to this specific view. I thought of this solution after seeing that there is a concept of "scrap" and "recycle" for recyclerview, but I am not so sure if this method is even possible because I think I have only vaguely understood this side of recyclerview.

That being said, my question is are there ways for me to set the number of views to be recycled for a recycled view? Or even better, having one view from being recycled for items other than the "expanded" item?

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT:

here's my (I know it's very messy I'm sorry...) code for my adapter:

```
public class DrinkMenuItem extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrinkMenuItem.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ViewGroup parent;
    private ArrayList<Drink> menu;
    private ArrayList<DrinkSelected> selected;
    private DrinkMenuBasketItem selectedAdapter;

    public int expanded = -1;
    public boolean expandedVisible = false;

    private DrinkMenuDropdownItem dropdownAdapter;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public RelativeLayout layout;
        public TextView name, price;
        public ListView dropdown;
        public RelativeLayout basket;
        public boolean tabbed = false;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            layout = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_layout);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_name);
            price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_price);
            dropdown = (ListView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_dropdown_list);
            basket = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_basket_button);
        }
    }

    public DrinkMenuItem(Context context, ArrayList<Drink> menu, ArrayList<DrinkSelected> selected, DrinkMenuBasketItem selectedAdapter) {
        this.context = context;
        this.menu = menu;
        this.selected = selected;
        this.selectedAdapter = selectedAdapter;
        this.dropdownAdapter = null;
    }

    public void updateDropdown(int requestedOption, int responsedOptionitem) {
        dropdownAdapter.updateSelectedOption(requestedOption, responsedOptionitem);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        this.parent = parent;
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_drink_menu, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Drink d = menu.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(d.getName());
        holder.price.setText(d.getPrice() + d.totalAdditionalPrice() + "원");

        if(position == expanded) {
            //delete dropdown
            holder.dropdown.setAdapter(null);
            menu.get(position).returnToUnselected();
            holder.price.setText(menu.get(position).getPrice() + "원");
            setListViewHeight(holder.dropdown);

            //reset dropdown-related stuff
            holder.tabbed = false;
            holder.basket.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        setOnClickEvent(holder, position, parent);
    }

    private void setOnClickEvent(final ViewHolder holder, final int position, final ViewGroup parent) {
        holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!holder.tabbed) {
                    //close dropdown of expanded view
                    if(expanded != -1) notifyItemChanged(expanded);
                    //make dropdown
                    dropdownAdapter = new DrinkMenuDropdownItem(context, menu, position, holder.price);
                    holder.dropdown.setAdapter(dropdownAdapter);
                    setListViewHeight(holder.dropdown);
                    //set dropdown-related stuff
                    holder.tabbed = true;
                    holder.basket.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    expanded = position;
                    expandedVisible = true;

                   ((RecyclerView) parent).smoothScrollToPosition(position);
                } else {
                    //delete dropdown
                    holder.dropdown.setAdapter(null);
                    menu.get(position).returnToUnselected();
                    holder.price.setText(menu.get(position).getPrice() + "원");
                    setListViewHeight(holder.dropdown);
                    expanded = -1;
                    expandedVisible = false;

                    //reset dropdown-related stuff
                    holder.tabbed = false;
                    holder.basket.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: add your `Adapter` code here. Most probable you would have to reinitialize every view so it does not get messed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly same issue in my project. I did not succeed solving it with `recyclerView`. But the solution would be one of the following:

1. Create an `expandableListView` instead of `recyclerView` and everything will work great.
2. Create a `ScrollView`, and put a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`. Then, create a loop and insert all your custom views, and set click listener where you wish to expand.
3. Use an Expandable RecyclerView Library like one of these:
   https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview
   https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: Thank you so much! I have implemented this to my app but has some issues with my groups "seemingly" being recycled, as the group names gets repeated when they are supposed to. I am not using the "dataProvider" method as the example shows, but rather fill in the group and item data from an arraylist of my own parcelable object. Also, I'm seeing the errors of the group name not being "bound" automatically upon scroll as I see that a certain amount of group names being recycled over and over. Do you happen to know how or why this issues occur?

Comment: I did not quite understand what example are you talking about? And what way did you choose in order to solve your issue?

Comment: oh sorry for being not clear there. I decided to use the example from https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview this one.

Comment: Sorry, but I would need more information on that, and how exactly that works. Also this is another question. Accept this answer and create another question with the issue you are facing now.